# Validation error in Entity framework when inserting data into the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I am trying to insert classifications data into a `Classifications` table in my database with Entity framework. The issue is that it gives me this error:

> {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See
> 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}

This is my code:

```
 public class Classifications
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public virtual int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public virtual string Classification { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Movie")]
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Series> Series { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my method for adding classifications:

```
 public static void InsertClassification(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var classification = new Classifications() { Classification = name };
                using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
                {
                    db.Classifications.Add(classification);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Added Classification");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cound not add classification");
            }
        }
```

The error is being given on the `db.saveChanges()`. With debug it checks this method but instead to print the added data message it goes to the Exception.

I am running it on my Main methoh.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string name = "ClassificationTest";
           Classifications.InsertClassification(name);


        }
    }
```

Can somebody help me solve this issue ?

Comment: It may be caused by the [Required] tag on top of the Movies, Series and Preferences.

Comment: And what **are** the `EntityValidationErrors`? Check via `ex` via the Locals window

Comment: In the locals window it just says : System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException}

Comment: Yes it was because of the [Required] fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove Required for this properties or create these lists before SaveChanges()

```
 [ForeignKey("Movie")]
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Series> Series { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual List<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why?

Comment: It is written in my answer already. Attribute [Requiered]  demands that property should not be null.  For example   Movies=new List<Movies>{ ...}